# Bind Foundation 5 Clearing to dynamically loaded images

Tags: ajax, jquery, zurb-foundation

Title pretty much sums it up.

I'm building an AJAX heavy website built on Foundation 5.

I have products being loaded dynamically via AJAX, each product has a few images which I want to display nicely using Foundation 5's Clearing.js. The newly created elements retrieved via AJAX do not trigger clearing functions when clicked ( new elements added using .html() ).

The way I see it, I have two prominent solutions:

a) Somehow rebind the clearing events to the newly added elements; or

b) Hook into the Clearing.js to manually trigger opening/closing using Jquery's `.on()` function (not sure how to call these functions manually? And it seems hacky).

I have previously come accross a similar problem with event binding using Foundations Abide, but was able use this function call to rebind events:

```
$('#signup-form').foundation({bindings: 'events'});
```

But this approach is not working, as I can't find any docs for this.

Can anybody suggest a solution or point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not had much love on this question, here or from Zurb.

I've now found that you can initialize specific components of foundation like this:

`$(document).foundation('clearing');`

This seems to be working for me now, although It's still not clear to me whether this is re-initializing the existing foundation instance, or creating a new instance of foundation every time it is called.

Comment: Know this is old, but did you solved your problem? I'm having almost the same issue.. but in my case I'm using foundation clearing with angularJS. Short story, I have created a photoalbum directive. When the user clicks on the image, it calls an API to retrieve the rest of the images and it open up with the clearing lightbox. Fun thing is that only sometimes it doesn't.